# Excel formula that concatenate the time

Tags: excel

Apologies for the inconvenience here is the updated screenshot of what the input and expected result needed. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Please use this [tool](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to refine your sample data and expected output. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Upload some example with snap images on your question what you have tried or mention the exact method that you need to know. The Question is incomplete for understanding your needs.

Comment: You can use Power Query easily for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

**VBA Method:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub TEST()

    Dim LastRowA As Long, LastRowD As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim Name As String, StartingTime As String, EndingTime As String

    j = 0

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To LastRowA

            If i >= j Then

                StartingTime = .Range("A" & i).Value
                Name = .Range("B" & i).Value

                For j = i + 1 To LastRowA + 1

                    If .Range("B" & j).Value <> Name Then

                        EndingTime = .Range("A" & j - 1).Value
                        LastRowD = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

                        .Range("D" & LastRowD + 1).Value = Name

                        If StartingTime = EndingTime Then
                            .Range("E" & LastRowD + 1).Value = StartingTime
                        Else
                            .Range("E" & LastRowD + 1).Value = StartingTime & "-" & EndingTime
                        End If

                        Exit For

                    End If

                Next j

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

**Results:**

[image]

**Excel Method:**

Import and drag down the below formulas

**Formula in cell D2:**`=LOOKUP(2,1/(COUNTIF($D$1:D1,$B$1:$B$8)=0),$B$1:$B$8)`

**Formula in cell E2:**`=IF(INDEX($A$1:$A$8,MATCH(D2,$B$1:$B$8,0))= LOOKUP(2,1/($B$1:$B$8=D2),$A$1:$A$8),LOOKUP(2,1/($B$1:$B$8=D2),$A$1:$A$8),INDEX($A$1:$A$8,MATCH(D2,$B$1:$B$8,0)) & "-" & LOOKUP(2,1/($B$1:$B$8=D2),$A$1:$A$8))`

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your swift response but is there other way to like have it just as an excel formula and not vba? although i might try this one as well.

Comment: If the answer helps you please vote it to help others